# SQL lag to row which meets condition

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table which contains measures taken on random dates, partitioned by the site at which they were taken.

| site | date | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB1234 | 2022-12-09 | 1 |
| AB1234 | 2022-06-11 | 2 |
| AB1234 | 2019-05-22 | 3 |
| AB1234 | 2017-01-30 | 4 |
| CD5678 | 2022-11-01 | 5 |
| CD5678 | 2020-04-10 | 6 |
| CD5678 | 2017-04-10 | 7 |
| CD5678 | 2017-01-22 | 8 |

In order to calculate a year on year growth, I want to have an additional field for each record which contains the previous measurement at that site. The challenging part is that I only want the previous which occurred more than a year in the past.

Like so:

| site | date | measurement | previous_measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB1234 | 2022-12-09 | 1 | 3 |
| AB1234 | 2022-06-11 | 2 | 3 |
| AB1234 | 2019-05-22 | 3 | 4 |
| AB1234 | 2017-01-30 | 4 | NULL |
| CD5678 | 2022-11-01 | 5 | 6 |
| CD5678 | 2020-04-10 | 6 | 7 |
| CD5678 | 2017-04-10 | 7 | NULL |
| CD5678 | 2017-01-22 | 8 | NULL |

It feels like it should be possible with a window function, but I can't work it out.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon Athena engine version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference-0003.html)  incorporated from Trino. If it has incorporated [full support for frame type RANGE](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html#-full-support-for-frame-type-range) for window functions you can use that:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(site, date, measurement) as (
    values ('AB1234', date '2022-12-09', 1),
    ('AB1234', date '2022-06-11', 2),
    ('AB1234', date '2019-05-22', 3),
    ('AB1234', date '2017-01-30', 4),
    ('CD5678', date '2022-11-01', 5),
    ('CD5678', date '2020-04-10', 6),
    ('CD5678', date '2017-04-10', 7),
    ('CD5678', date '2017-01-22', 8)
)

-- query
select *,
    last_value(measurement) over (
        partition by site
        order by date
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND interval '1' year PRECEDING)
from dataset;
```

Output:

| site | date | measurement | _col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD5678 | 2017-01-22 | 8 | NULL |
| CD5678 | 2017-04-10 | 7 | NULL |
| CD5678 | 2020-04-10 | 6 | 7 |
| CD5678 | 2022-11-01 | 5 | 6 |
| AB1234 | 2017-01-30 | 4 | NULL |
| AB1234 | 2019-05-22 | 3 | 4 |
| AB1234 | 2022-06-11 | 2 | 3 |
| AB1234 | 2022-12-09 | 1 | 3 |